# how to return numeric variable in inside entities custom field output from drupal 7 so that I can have a different image on each entity page

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

In the following example code which is mostly copied from krumo output of Devel module, this shows the exact path to where the field I'm trying to show is located but the "11" in this example is a custom entity id (a group gid from the Group module, not OG) and this number is associated to the individual group that is the variable I want to pass into my template code.

```
$img_items = $variables['page']['content']['system_main']['group'][11]['field_header_image'][0]['#item']['uri'];
<img src="<?php print image_style_url("header_image_1200", $img_items); ?>" />
```

How can I make that "11" be a wildcard?

Comment: You use the [drupal] tag, but did you read its description? However, whatever you do with this question, it requires a lot more details to make it answerable.

Comment: Same goes for the [group] tag: read its description. And I removed the [entity-framework] tag because it's not clear how it is related.